# return 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, return

I am kind of new to C++ and I was doing a physics simulation in python which was taking forever to finish so I decided to switch to C++, and I don t understand how to make a function which will return a 2D array (or 3D array)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
// #include <complex> //

using namespace std;

double** psiinit(int L, int n, double alpha){
    double yj[400][400] = {};
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        double xi[400] = {};
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            xi[i] = exp(-(pow((i-(L/4)), 2) + (pow((j-(L/4)), 2)))/alpha) / (sqrt(2)*3.14159*alpha);
        };
        yj[j] = xi;
    };
    return yj;
}

int main(){
    int L = 10;
    int n = 400;
    int nt = 200*n;
    double alpha = 1;
    double m = 1;
    double hbar = 1;

    double x[n] = {};
    double y[n] = {};
    double t[nt] = {};

    double psi[nt][n][n] = {};
    psi[0] = psiinit(L, n, alpha);

    cout << psi <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have look for answers but it doesn't seems to be for my kind of problems

Thanks

Comment: Make a class that represents a 2D array.  In that class have a linear `std::vector<double>` and convert the x,y position into the linear vector.  Return that 2D class.

Comment: Your array is static, on the stack, only defined inside `psiinit`. So you can not return it. Returning it the way you do returns the address to something that stops existing at the end of your function. Why not write nice C++ and use `std::vector`? You're really writing C in C++.

Comment: `double [400][400]` and `double**` are unrelated types.

Comment: Of the proposed alternatives: If you have fixed size anyway, then `std::array<std::array<double, Columns>, Rows>` is good choice, you get the `[row][column]` indexing for free – note, though, that when defining the array of arrays you have to invert order of columns and rows. That's the consequence of the (unfortunate?) decision of the standard's committee to have the type precede the size in the template parameters – a vector of vectors comes with (hidden) double pointer indirection with every element access as well as multiple array allocations, so a linear vector (see @Eljay) is superior.

Comment: You may want to return a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`. Or, because you have fixed dimensions there, make it more compact with `std::unique_ptr<std::array<std::array<double, 400>, 400>>`. Allocate it with (e.g.) `auto yj = std::make_unique<std::array<std::array<double, 400>, 400>>();` and the rest should be straightforward. You can return, pass and `std::move` a `std::unique_ptr`, which expresses ownership and handles deallocation correctly. For scope-limited sharing you can use a raw pointer from `.get()`. For thread-safe reference-counted sharing use `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: OT: change `i-(L/4)` into something like `i - L / 4.0` if you want the "correct" value when `L` is not divisible by 4. Also, since C++20, you can find some mathematical constant in [`<numbers>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're new to c++ you should read about the concepts of heap and stack, and about stack frames. There are a ton of good resources for that.

In short, when you declare a C-style array (such as `yj`), it is created in the stack frame of the function, and therefore there are no guarantees about it once you exit the frame, and your program invokes undefined behavior when it references that returned array.

There are 3 options:

1. Pass the array to the function as an output parameter (very C-style and not recommended).
2. Wrap the array in a class (like `std::array` already does for you), in which case it remains on the stack and is copied to the calling frame when returned, but then its size has to be known at compile time.
3. Allocate the array on the heap and return it, which seems to me to best suit your case. `std::vector` does that for you:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> psiinit(int L, int n, double alpha){
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> yj;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        std::vector<double> xi;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            const int value = exp(-(pow((i-(L/4)), 2) + (pow((j-(L/4)), 2)))/alpha) / (sqrt(2)*3.14159*alpha);
            xi.push_back(value);
        }

        yj.push_back(xi);
    }
    return yj;
}
```

If you're concerned with performance and all of your inner vectors are of a fixed size `N`, it might be better to use `std::vector<std::array<double, N>>`.

Answer (score 1):

Either make a wrapper as said above, or use a vector of vectors.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

auto get_2d_array()
{
    // use std::vector since it will allocate (the large amount of) data on the heap
    // construct a vector of 400 vectors with 400 doubles each
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> arr(400, std::vector<double>(400));
    arr[100][100] = 3.14;
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    auto arr = get_2d_array();
    std::cout << arr[100][100];
}
```

Comment: `std::array` (as size is fixed) is an alternative.

Comment: @Jarod42 I considered that but if size will be bigger then 400 there might be some issues with stack space . Other then that a good solution too

Comment: Considering the fact that if size does not change, std::array would be a better option, if size does changes std::vector will be the option

Comment: With `std::unique_ptr<std::array<std::array<double, 400>, 400>>` there will be no issues with stack space.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of arrays, pointers and return values is incomplete. I cannot write you a whole tutorial on the topic but I recommend you read up on this.

In the mean time, I recommend you use `std::vector` instead of C-style arrays and treat your multidimensional arrays as 1D vectors with proper indexing, e.g. `cell = vector[row * cols + col]`

Something like this:

```
#include <cmath>
// using std::exp, M_PI, M_SQRT2
#include <vector>

std::vector<double> psiinit(int L, int n, double alpha) {
    std::vector<double> yj(n * n);
    double div = M_SQRT2 * M_PI * alpha;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        double jval = j - L/4;
        jval = jval * jval;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            double ival = i - L/4;
            ival = ival * ival;
            yj[j * n + i] = std::exp(-(ival + jval) / alpha) / div;
        }
    }
    return yj;
}
```

Addendum: There are also specialized libraries to support matrices better and faster. For example Eigen
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html

Answer (score 0):

heap allocating and returning that pointer will also work...
instead of

```
double yj[400][400] = {};
```

do,

```
double** yj; 
yj = new double*[400]; 
yj[i] = new double[400];
```

then just,

```
return yj;
```

Comment: That would be OK in C, although it may be better to allocate a compact multi-dimensional array instead of a Java-style one. In C++ I would use more of the standard library, such as `std::array` and, even more importantly, `std::unique_ptr`.